# Forecast weekdays time series data

Tags: r

I have time-series data from 2002-11-01 to 2019-12-24 excluding weekends and holiday and I want to forecast upcoming values based on this data. I want to forecast value for only weekdays, while not considering weekends. I don't know which model will be applicable to this forecasting.

I was unable to put the whole data. But for other years values are similar to these.

Comment: how many steps ahead ?

Comment: @hello_friend for next 30 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way of producing the forecast:

```
# Vector of packages required in session:  necessary_packages => character vector
necessary_packages <- c("forecast", "ggplot2")

# Create a vector containing the names of any packages needing installation:
# new_pacakges => character vector
new_packages <- 
  necessary_packages[!(necessary_packages %in% installed.packages()[, "Package"])]

# If the vector has more than 0 values, install the new pacakges
# (and their associated dependencies): stdout
if(length(new_packages) > 0){install.packages(new_packages, dependencies = TRUE)}

# Initialise the packages in the session: stdout => list of booleans
lapply(necessary_packages, require, character.only = TRUE)

# Nullify outliers in the data.frame: out_free_df => data.frame
out_free_df <- within(df, {
  Price <- sapply(df$Price, function(x){
       ifelse(x %in% boxplot.stats(df$Price)$out, NA, x)
      }
    )
  }
)

# Interpolate the Nullified values: prices => numeric vector
interped_df <- within(out_free_df, {
    Price <- ifelse(
      is.na(out_free_df$Price),
      approx(out_free_df$Price, n = nrow(df), 
             method = "linear")$y[which(is.na(out_free_df$Price))],
      out_free_df$Price
    )
  }
)

# Difference the logged prices: ldp => timeseries obj
ldp <- diff(log(msts(interped_df$Price, seasonal.periods = c(5, (365.25 * (5/7))))))

# Look at the seasonality of the prices: stdout => graphics
ggseasonplot(ldp, polar = TRUE)

# Look at a line chart of the the prices: stdout => graphics
autoplot(ldp)

# Plot the auto-correlation function: stdout => graphics 
ggAcf(ldp)

# No. of diffs required to make series stationary: n_diffs => numeric vector
n_diffs <- ndiffs(ldp, alpha = 0.05, "kpss")

# Function to produce the forecast: forecast_func => function
forecast_func <- function(fcast_vec, n_ahead, include_weekends = TRUE){

  # Extend n_ahead to compensate for weekends: n_ahead => numeric vector
  n_steps <-
    ifelse(include_weekends, n_ahead, (n_ahead + ceiling((n_ahead / 7) * 2)))

  # Store a scalar to adjust for daily seasonality dependent upon whether
  # weekends are included or not: daily_seas => numeric vector
  daily_seas <- ifelse(include_weekends, 7, 5)

  # Store a scalar to adjust for yearly seasonality dependent upon whether
  # weekends are included or not: yearly_seas => numeric vector:
  yearly_seas <- ifelse(include_weekends, 365.25, (365.25 * (5 / 7)))

  # Lock pseudo-randon number generator: set.seed(2020) => .GlobalEnv
  set.seed(2020)

  # Cast the forecast vector to a time-series object with 5 daily
  # and yearly seasonality: fcast_vec => ts object
  fcast_ts <-
    msts(fcast_vec,
         seasonal.periods = ifelse(
           length(fcast_vec) > yearly_seas,
           daily_seas,
           c(daily_seas, yearly_seas)
         ))

  # Store a function to caclulate the RMSE: rmse => function 
  rmse <- function(actual_vec, pred_vec){sqrt(mean((pred_vec - actual_vec)**2))}

  # Fit an ets model: fit_ets => list
  fit_ets <- ets(fcast_ts)

  # Fit a holt-winters additive forecast: fit_hwa => list
  fit_hwa <- hw(fcast_ts, seasonal = "additive")

  # Fit a tbats model: fit_tbt => list
  fit_tbt <- tbats(fcast_ts)

  # Fit an auto.arima model: fit_arm => list
  fit_arm <- auto.arima(fcast_ts)

  # Fit a neural network model: fit_nn => list 
  fit_nn <- nnetar(fcast_ts, maxit = 150)

  # Store the fit objects in a list: fit_list => list
  fit_list <- list(fit_ets, fit_hwa, fit_tbt, fit_arm, fit_nn)

  # Select the best model: fcast_fit => list
  fcast_fit <- 
    fit_list[[which.min(sapply(fit_list, function(x){rmse(fcast_ts, x$fitted)}))]]

  # Produce the forecast n steps ahead: forecasted_raw => data.frame  
  forecasted_raw <- data.frame(forecast(fcast_fit, h = n_steps))

  # Clean up column names of the forecast: forecasted_df => data.frame 
  forecasted_df <- 
    setNames(forecasted_raw, gsub("\\s+|[.]", "_", tolower(names(forecasted_raw))))

  # Define the return object: forecasted_df => .GlobalEnv
  return(forecasted_df)
}

# Store a vector time_steps to forecast ahead: n => numeric vector
n <- 30

# Store a boolean scalar to determine whether or not weekends are considered: 
# iw => boolean
iw <- FALSE

# Apply the function to differenced, logged prices: intermediat_res => data.frame
intermediate_res <- forecast_func(c(0, diff(log(interped_df$Price))), n, 
                                  include_weekends = iw)

# Append the forecasted prices to the data.frame: df_w_fcast => data.frame
df_w_fcast <- rbind(
  transform(df, Type = "actuals"),
  data.frame(
    Date = c(seq.Date(max(df$Date)+1, as.Date(ifelse(iw, (max(df$Date) + n), 
                            (max(df$Date) + (n + ceiling((n/7) * 2)))),
             "%Y-%m-%d", origin = as.Date("1970-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d")), 1)),
    Price = exp(cumsum(
      c((intermediate_res$point_forecast[1] + log(df$Price[nrow(df)])),
        intermediate_res$point_forecast[2:nrow(intermediate_res)]))),
    Type = "forecast"
  )
)

# Get the indexes of records we want to exclude: rm_idx => numeric vector
rm_idx <- if(!(iw)){which(weekdays(df_w_fcast$Date) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"))}

# Subset out weekends: w_e_free_fcast => data.frame
w_e_free_fcast <- if(!is.null(rm_idx)){df_w_fcast[-rm_idx,]}else{df_w_fcast}

# Chart it using ggplot2: list => stoudt (graphics device) 
ggplot(w_e_free_fcast, aes(x = Date, y = Price, group = Type, colour = Type)) +
  geom_line()
```

Comment: can you please post the output. When I an running your code I m not getting my desired output. The point forecasted is very different from the actual point.

Comment: @xyz try that, give an upvote and accept the answer if it does what you desire. The point forecasted on my machine isn't that different RMSE of auto.arima() model chosen is approx. ~370. Also if you want to improve it feel free, this should be a starting point for you.

Comment: @xyz if you want to improve it you should look at the parameters / functions used.

Comment: @xyz this model is a quick and dirty one. If you want to understand how to forecast well a good start is this book https://otexts.com/fpp2/ and read Rob Hyndmans blog here: https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/

Comment: @xyz check out my edited code and accept my answer!

Comment: can you plz check your last edit. I think you missed something.

Comment: @xyz you were right I had buggered it up. Please see now. :)

Comment: error is resolved but there is a problem in the output the forecasted value is same for all 30 points and the forecasted value is similar to the last value in the data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212845/discussion-between-xyz-and-hello-friend).